# How to find the area of the part of sphere that lies in a parabloid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Suppose a sphere is described by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=4z$, How do we find the area of the part of sphere that lies in a parabloid $z=x^2+y^2$ if we **have to** use spherical parametrization?

First I have issue setting up spherical coordinate

I think we rewrite the equation as $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=4$, but then how do we adjust the $x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta, z=\rho\cos\phi$?

Comment: That boils down to finding the volume of a solid of revolution, whose section $z=z_0$ has a simple area. Just integrate the areas of the $z$-sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, the sphere has equation $\rho = 4 \cos \phi$.

So you need to parametrize the surface as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\overbrace{(4\cos \phi)}^{=\rho} \sin \phi \cos \theta \\
y=(4cos \phi) \sin \phi \sin \theta \quad \text{with}\quad  (\phi,\theta)\in D=[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \times [0,2\pi]\\
z=(4cos \phi) \cos \phi  \\
\end{cases}
$$
The area then equals
$$
A = \iint_D \mid\mid \vec{r}_{\phi}\times \vec{r}_{\theta} \mid \mid \; d\phi d\theta
$$

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note that the area does not change if you shift the origin $2$ units along the $z$ axis so that you have the sphere 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4
$$
and the paraboloid 
$$
z+2=x^2+y^2
$$
With this new coordinate system, you can use the classical spherical coordinates, but the bounds in $\phi$ will differ.